# Acumatica - SelectFrom Returning Null Despite Passing a Valid ID

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am creating an extension to Acumatica's `EmployeeMaint` graph. In a custom Action I am creating, I have a need to access the `BAccount` associated with the employee's branch:

```
   public PXAction<EPEmployee> CreatePREmp;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Employee", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
        public IEnumerable createPREmp(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            var employeeSettingsGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PREmployeePayrollSettingsMaint>();
            PREmployee payrollEmployee = PayrollEmployee.SelectSingle();
            if (payrollEmployee == null)
            {

                var bID = Base.Employee.Current.ParentBAccountID.GetValueOrDefault();

                Branch branch = SelectFrom<Branch>
                .Where<Branch.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.View.Select(Base, bID);

            BAccount bAccount = SelectFrom<BAccount>
                    .Where<BAccount.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.View.Select(Base, bID);

             // Code removed for brevity

                return adapter.Get();

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Employee already exists!");
            }

        }
```

The `SelectFrom<BAccount>` statement is the problem. It is returning `null` even though I have verified through debugging and viewing the underlying DB that `bID` is indeed valid. Additionally, the statement preceding it (`SelectFrom<Branch>`) works just fine, something which I assume would not be the case if `bID` was not associated with a valid BAccount.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: May it be that you have some restrictions configured in the system for Branches/Customers?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, what type of restrictions may cause this? For testing purposes, I am using the admin user with full privileges? Thanks.

Comment: RestrictionGroupsByBranch my cause this kind of issue if the account your are selecting is a branch

Answer (score 1):

*Since no version was specified my testing was done against 2021 R1.*

The problem you are running into is that there is already a data view for BAccount on the EmployeeMaint graph. In general you're not supposed to have multiple data views for the same data access class on a given graph. I know there are some exceptions, but I don't know exactly what they are. When you find yourself in this place, what is usually happening is the SQL generated has join and where conditions from multiple of the declared data views for the data access class which ends up forcing the query to return nothing.

To get around this there are several solutions (listed in order I'd likely use them, though all were tested successfully).

**Solution 1 - Use BAccount.PK.Find**

In a more recent version of Acumatica (20r2 I think) they added a PK class within the data access classes. This class has a static function Find which retrieves a record based on its key values. I do not know all the rules around this but I haven't ever experienced an issue with the existence of data view on the graph for the data access class. It seems like the cleanest code if you're retrieving by ID.

```
    public PXAction<EPEmployee> CreatePREmp;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Employee", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
    public IEnumerable createPREmp(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        var employeeSettingsGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PREmployeePayrollSettingsMaint>();
        PREmployee payrollEmployee = employeeSettingsGraph.PayrollEmployee.SelectSingle();
        if (payrollEmployee == null)
        {

            var bID = Base.Employee.Current.ParentBAccountID.GetValueOrDefault();

            Branch branch =
                SelectFrom<Branch>
                    .Where<Branch.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
                .View.Select(Base, bID);

            BAccount bAccount = BAccount.PK.Find(Base, bID);

            // Code removed for brevity

            return adapter.Get();

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Employee already exists!");
        }
```

**Solution 2 - Use a different data access class**

You can use a different data access class (that isn't in a data view on the graph) that points to the same data. Since BAccount is a common one, Acumatica already has BAccount2 that can be used for this purpose in this instance.

```
    public PXAction<EPEmployee> CreatePREmp;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Employee", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
    public IEnumerable createPREmp(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        var employeeSettingsGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PREmployeePayrollSettingsMaint>();
        PREmployee payrollEmployee = employeeSettingsGraph.PayrollEmployee.SelectSingle();
        if (payrollEmployee == null)
        {

            var bID = Base.Employee.Current.ParentBAccountID.GetValueOrDefault();

            Branch branch =
                SelectFrom<Branch>
                    .Where<Branch.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
                .View.Select(Base, bID);

            BAccount2 bAccount = 
                SelectFrom<BAccount2>
                    .Where<BAccount2.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
                    .View.Select(Base, bID);

            // Code removed for brevity

            return adapter.Get();

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Employee already exists!");
        }
```

**Solution 3 - Use a different graph**

You can use a different Graph context for your query, where the graph context doesn't have a reference a data view for the desired data access class. Note in this example I use new PXGraph(). The documentation always says not to use the new operator for graph instantiation but I have gotten code (at least 5 times) from Acumatica developers where to get around this very problem you're experiencing they used new PXGraph().

```
    public PXAction<EPEmployee> CreatePREmp;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Import Employee", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
    public IEnumerable createPREmp(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        var employeeSettingsGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PREmployeePayrollSettingsMaint>();
        PREmployee payrollEmployee = employeeSettingsGraph.PayrollEmployee.SelectSingle();
        if (payrollEmployee == null)
        {

            var bID = Base.Employee.Current.ParentBAccountID.GetValueOrDefault();

            Branch branch =
                SelectFrom<Branch>
                    .Where<Branch.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
                .View.Select(Base, bID);

            BAccount bAccount = 
                SelectFrom<BAccount>
                    .Where<BAccount.bAccountID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
                    .View.Select(new PXGraph(), bID);

            // Code removed for brevity

            return adapter.Get();

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Employee already exists!");
        }
```